# How do I filter the options in multiple selects based on the option selected in one select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have three select boxes on a page: Company, Vendor, Type.  I have the following function that when I select a company, it will filter the vendor options to only show vendors for the company selected.

```
jQuery("#companySel").change(function() {
   if (jQuery(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      jQuery(this).data('options', jQuery('#vendorId option').clone());
   }
   var id = jQuery(this).val();
   if (id === '') {
      var options = "";
   } else {
      var options = jQuery(this).data('options').filter('[companyId=' + id + ']');
   }
   jQuery('#vendorId').html(options);
});
```

That function works great for the one select box.  I can do a second one for the Type select box and it also works great:

```
jQuery("#companySel").change(function() {
   if (jQuery(this).data('options') == undefined) {
      jQuery(this).data('options', jQuery('#typeId option').clone());
   }
   var id = jQuery(this).val();
   if (id === '') {
      var options = "";
   } else {
      var options = jQuery(this).data('options').filter('[companyId=' + id + ']');
   }
   jQuery('#typeId').html(options);
});
```

What I can't figure out how to do is to combine them. I want to select a company and then it filter BOTH the vendors for that company and the types for that company.

When I try to combine them, it works the first time; however, the second time you change the company select box, it tries to filter the filtered list, not the original list prior to the filter.

Comment: Without seeing the combination code, I can spot a few problems with the code above. You are assigning the same data options with first the vendors, and you assign the types on the same data options . So you might want to change that so instead you assign to vendors, and types seperately (jQuery(this).data('vendors').... Secondly, if your combined implementation you are not doing some sort of resetting, then the first check inside you function will find options is not undefined and will continue with the filtered list, rather than resetting back to the full list again.